# Can I say "government of the prefecture"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to express like this sentence,

"According to the government of Kanagawa prefecture, there is no child who is waiting for a nursery school."

Should I use "government" or is it better to use "public administration of Kanagawa prefecture"?

Comment: The form I usually see is "Kanagawa *prefectural government*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Government" is fine. You can use "public administration" if you want to, but I would understand "government" better.
Also, I would write "Kanagawa Prefecture" with a capital "P" because it is a proper noun.

Comment: I agree. Short answer, yes, you may. Long answer, but there is an argument for localization (using what other people use in your intended audience). For example, in Taiwan, I might say things like "district" when in New York City, I might say "borough" (essentially the same).